# I want the output of the following query using a stored procedure in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, select, procedure

```
select username,expiry_date,sysdate,FLOOR(expiry_date-sysdate) as "days left"
from dba_users
where username in ( 'ABCD',   'TSTL',    'HDO',    'LOTER',
  'SMB',    'UStR',    'N3P',    'FADT',    'FRE',    'VMSV',    'CHATY',
  'PBKMIN',    'LMSROD',    'UKPSPREPROD')
order by expiry_date;
```

Comment: You don't need a stored procedure to get the output of this query - what do you actually need the procedure to do?

Answer (score -1):

```
create or replace procedure XXX(p_rs out sys_refcursor)
as
begin

  open p_rs for
    select ......

end;
```